# Why does _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint() not work on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Why does `_objc_autoreleasePoolPrint()` work in OS X and does not on iOS?

**UPDATE**

I have no sample code because it is not depends on a specific code.

In osx i have:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
        _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

As a result i see in console:

```
objc[45473]: ##############
objc[45473]: AUTORELEASE POOLS for thread 0x7fff764ae310
objc[45473]: 2 releases pending.
objc[45473]: [0x100803000]  ................  PAGE  (hot) (cold)
objc[45473]: [0x100803038]  ################  POOL 0x100803038
objc[45473]: [0x100803040]       0x100102ff0  __NSArrayI
objc[45473]: ##############
```

And the same code in the `main.m` (or in any other place) in iOS project occurs with nothing in console. When i'm trying `po _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint()` in the debugger i have `nil`

```
(lldb) po _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint()
 nil
```

Comment: The implementation calls out to `(_v)cprintf()`, so are you sure you're actually looking at the right console for output?

Comment: The question is too short. Please provide more context, and/or sample code.

Comment: @CodaFi i've seen all of them :)

Comment: @david.pfx added some code

Comment: You could also try `[NSAutoreleasePool showPools]`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare first

```
extern void _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
```

then you can call

```
_objc_autoreleasePoolPrint()
```